# YOLO V5 custom object detection : csv output

Tags: python, object-detection, yolov5

I managed to train the YOLO V5 model on my customed data and I'm having great results. I was just wondering how I could export the bonding boxes in a csv or txt file in which I'd have the coordinates and the score of prediction.
I've read that I'll need to change the detect.py file but I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the line 159 at https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/master/detect.py

there is an argument to save txt files, usage shoud be something like:

```
python detect.py --weights yolov5s.pt --save-txt det.txt
```

the other option is to:

```
import pandas as pd
detections = []

...
detections.append(line)

... 
#condition to save
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict( {'detections': detections})
df.to_csv("detections.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks I'm now able to get the coordinates of the bounding boxes, I was wondering if I could add to them the score of prediciton